# Wordpress on local host asks for FTP credentials on mac

Tags: wordpress, macos

Cannot update the wordpress plugin as I am constantly being asked about FTP credentials. I have tried using `define('FS_METHOD','direct');` but did not work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add this to the bottom of your wp-config.php file:

```
if(is_admin()) {
    add_filter('filesystem_method', create_function('$a', 'return "direct";' ));
    define( 'FS_CHMOD_DIR', 0751 );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

change the ownership of the Wordpress folder (that contains your wordpress installation) to  "_www" user which is the owner user of apache httpd service:

sudo chown -R _www wordpress

sudo chmod -R 755 wordpress

Comment: Worked as expected. 
Thanks